how to turn off swoosh sounds for sent and received text in iMessages on iPhone while I'm already in the thread?
when I'm using imessage and am looking at the conversation thread, new messages in that thread getting received and sent play "swoosh" sounds. I don't want to hear these, but I also don't want to silence everything, because I want to hear pings when I have my phone off.
How do I do this? When I go to sound -> haptics, there's settings for "Sent mail" and "received mail", but I have both set to "none", and besides, that's for Mail, not texts and imessages.
I'm using iphone 13 with ios 17.6.1
